# LogicAPP Flow to send mails from emails in JSON

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to make a flow with the trigger

"When an HTTP request is received"

In this case, when filling in some data on the web, a JSON with this structure is provided.

```
{
  "to": "email1@company.e, email2@company.es, email3@company.es",
  "body": "<h1>Text</h1>",
  "subject": "Upload information"
}
```

the number of emails can vary.

I want, when the JSON is received, the flow sends to all the emails found in JSON an email with the subject and the body.

Thank you

Comment: Show us your attempt and maybe we can help.

Comment: Do you want to send the email in a bulk request or to each person individually?

Comment: The idea is as follows, from a website, a person creates an event, to this event the email addresses of the people in our organization that we want to receive it are added, the website generates a Json with these addresses, event name as subject and a body of the message. This email with the subject and the body must reach each person individually.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve this just by replacing the to information's `,` to `;`. For demonstration purposes, I have taken the json from compose while you can take it from trigger itself.

[image]

[image]

Results:

[image]

Below is the flow of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "<h1>Text</h1>",
                    "subject": "Upload information",
                    "to": "email1@company.e, email2@company.es, email3@company.es"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@replace(body('Parse_JSON')?['to'],',',';')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('Compose')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "body": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "subject": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "to": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Body": "<p>@{body('Parse_JSON')}</p>",
                        "Importance": "Normal",
                        "Subject": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['body']",
                        "To": "@{outputs('Compose_2')}"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow,It works, I don't see your nickname but thank you very much, this flow works perfectly.

Comment: I'm thinking about one thing, this flow must be activated when a colleague completes a website, which generates a JSON, this JSON will vary in "subject", "body" and "emails" each time, with this flow the corresponding emails will be sent to the new emails with the new subject and body?

Comment: @GreenLynx yes, it will work if the json is in the same format else I can provide you answer if the schema is not the same for each run.